# div opacity on scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade out the each blocks while scrolling top. When the particular div reached browser top it should slowly fade away.

I have tried but the problem here is that it is fading out all the divs since all divs have the same class name. I do not want to change the html structure for some reasons.

Is there any way to apply this effect on each divs?

```
var header = $('.content');
var range = 200;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var offset = header.offset().top;
    var height = header.outerHeight();
    offset = offset + height / 2;
    var calc = 1 - (scrollTop - offset + range) / range;

    header.css({ 'opacity': calc });

    if ( calc > '1' ) {
      header.css({ 'opacity': 1 });
    } else if ( calc < '0' ) {
      header.css({ 'opacity': 0 });
    }

});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nr7ar1jr/2/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr7ar1jr/6/). Basically, I did the calculation for each `div` separately by wrapping your code with `.each`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this different version of answer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr7ar1jr/8/).

```
header.each(function(){
if($(this).position().top - scrollTop  <= 0){    
          $(this).css({ 'opacity': 0 });      
}else{
     $(this).css({ 'opacity': 1 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to calculate the opacity for each element of the class.

Also you have to add a parent element with overflow-y:auto;

```js
var parent = $("#parent");
var childs = $(".content");
var offset_top = 0;
var range = 200;

parent.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop<20){
        childs.css("opacity",1);
    }
    else{
        childs.each(function(){
            var top = $(this).offset().top - offset_top;
            var height = $(this).height();
            var offset = height/4;
   
            var opacity = (top+ height - offset) / range;

            if(opacity>1) opacity = 1;
            else if(opacity<0) opacity = 0;

            $(this).css("opacity",opacity);
     });
    }
});
```

```css
div {color:#fff; padding:5%}
.content:nth-child(1){background:blue}
.content:nth-child(2){background:grey}
.content:nth-child(3){background:black}
.content:nth-child(4){background:red}

body,html{
  height:100%;

}

#parent{
  height:50%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">

<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit perspiciatis temporibus accusantium aspernatur sint, commodi, dolor. Itaque, repudiandae ipsum consequatur, libero quisquam enim. Omnis architecto optio, eaque sapiente quia veritatis?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit perspiciatis temporibus accusantium aspernatur sint, commodi, dolor. Itaque, repudiandae ipsum consequatur, libero quisquam enim. Omnis architecto optio, eaque sapiente quia veritatis?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit perspiciatis temporibus accusantium aspernatur sint, commodi, dolor. Itaque, repudiandae ipsum consequatur, libero quisquam enim. Omnis architecto optio, eaque sapiente quia veritatis?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit perspiciatis temporibus accusantium aspernatur sint, commodi, dolor. Itaque, repudiandae ipsum consequatur, libero quisquam enim. Omnis architecto optio, eaque sapiente quia veritatis?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit perspiciatis temporibus accusantium aspernatur sint, commodi, dolor. Itaque, repudiandae ipsum consequatur, libero quisquam enim. Omnis architecto optio, eaque sapiente quia veritatis?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit perspiciatis temporibus accusantium aspernatur sint, commodi, dolor. Itaque, repudiandae ipsum consequatur, libero quisquam enim. Omnis architecto optio, eaque sapiente quia veritatis?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum animi quos magnam earum nam itaque, sint rerum quibusdam voluptatibus, ipsam accusamus libero accusantium eveniet voluptatem quas, est tenetur eius aliquid.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Okey @abarisone. Thanks for the suggestion.